# When I run my symfony application through Codeception functional tests Doctrine events are not fired

Tags: php, symfony, doctrine, codeception

I'm creating a set of Functional tests for a Symfony 5.4 application using Doctrine.

Upon creation of a record of a certain type I need to trigger the creation of a record in another table.

For that I've used an EventListener:

```
class AssetsRecordListener
{
  /**
   * @return void
   */
  public function onFlush(OnFlushEventArgs $eventArgs)
  {
    $em = $eventArgs->getObjectManager();
    $uow = $em->getUnitOfWork();

    $this->processInsertedRecords($uow, $em);

    $this->processUpdatedRecords($uow, $em);
  }
  ....
}
```

The thing is, when I test the app manually everything works ok, but when I try it within a CodeCeption run the test fails.

Here's my test code:

```
     * @param FunctionalTester $I
     * @param Example $example
     * @return void
     *
     * @throws Exception
     * @example (file="AUM.Pershing.1.xlsm",totalAUM="148257001.57",uploadDate="07/27/2022",provider="Pershing")
     * @example (file="AUM.Pershing.2.xlsm",totalAUM="3079945.61",uploadDate="07/28/2022",provider="Pershing")
     * @example (file="AUM.FCStone.1.xlsx",totalAUM="441807.31",uploadDate="07/29/2022",provider="FC Stone")
     * @example (file="AUM.FCStone.2.xlsx",totalAUM="62209684.83",uploadDate="08/02/2022",provider="FC Stone")
     */
    public function verifyCashierConcept(FunctionalTester $I, Example $example): void
    {
        $I->am('operator');
        $I->expectTo('see ' . $example['totalAUM'] . ' as value for '.$example['uploadDate'].' AUM in '.$example['provider'].' Cashier Concept Value');
        $this->buildBasicScenario($I);
        $this->uploadFile($I, $example['file']);
        $provider = $this->getProvider($I, $example['provider']);

        $I->seeInRepository(CashierConceptValue::class, [
            'date' => new DateTimeImmutable($example['uploadDate']),
            'concept' => $I->grabEntityFromRepository(CashierConcept::class, [
                'class' => CashierConcept::CLASS_AUM,
                'provider' => $provider,
            ]),
            'value' => $example['totalAUM'],
        ]);
    }
```

This is the configuration for the `services.yaml` file:

```
App\EventListeners\AssetsRecordListener:
    tags:
        - { name: doctrine.event_listener, event: onFlush }
```

I'm leaning towards some problem with the transaction model or something like that but I can't put my finger on it. Any idea? Thanks!

Comment: Can you share how was configured the listener in the service.yam?

Comment: Thanks @RicardoJesusRuiz. I added the details to the question